# React Native not working with wild card SSL

Tags: react-native, ssl-certificate, wildcard-subdomain

I have react native app when i try call API from normal SSL (direct domain) my app working perfect, but when I change to call API from domain using wildcard SSL is not working. Any idea to solve this issue ?